# Can I access enum property with string in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, enums

I have an enum of regions like this:

```
enum class Regions(val location:String){
   REGION_1("London"),
}
```

Is there a way to access the properties of region_1 with just a string like in the below function?

```
fun access(name:String){
    return Regions.<modifed_name>.location 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your string to enum using valueOf(value: string) and then use the location

```kotlin
fun access(name:String): String = Regions.valueOf(name.uppercase()).location
```

Comment: Note that this will crash the application if _name_ is not _REGION_1_, _REGION_2_, etc.

Comment: @lukas.j It will throw an exception (specifically, an `IllegalArgumentException`). Whether that causes a crash depends on whether it's caught anywhere, which thread it's running in, and the type of program.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum class Regions(val location: String) {
  REGION_1("London"),
  REGION_2("Berlin"),
  REGION_3("Pairs")
}

fun access(name:String): String {
  return Regions.values().firstOrNull() { it.name == name }?.location ?: "location not found"
}

println(access("REGION"))     // Output: location not found
println(access("REGION_2"))   // Output: Berlin
```